# How to compare nested lists in dataframe per row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, nested-lists, set-difference

I have a dataset that contains lists for values in two columns, and I want to be able to compare the lists with each other, for each row. For example, I have 3 groups, in which certain numbers are expected, and other numbers are observed. I want to compare the Observed column with the Expected column to see which numbers were expected, but not observed.

| Group | Expected | Observed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4:8 | c(4, 5, 7) |
| B | 7:12 | c(7, 8, 9, 10, 12) |
| C | 6:10 | c(6, 8, 10) |

I want an extra column called Missing, that contains all the values that are in Expected, but not Observed.

| Group | Expected | Observed | Missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4:8 | c(4, 5, 7) | c(6, 8) |
| B | 7:12 | c(7, 8, 9, 10, 12) | 11 |
| C | 6:11 | c(6, 8, 11) | c(7, 9, 10) |

I have tried to use setdiff() and base R, as it can find the differing values between two lists. However, I cannot get it to work in the way that it compares the lists per row.

```
df$Missing <- setdiff(df$Expected, df$Observed) 

df$Missing <- df$Expected[!(df$Expected %in% df$Observed)]
```

Both these options result in the full list of Expected. This is the output that I get:

| Group | Expected | Observed | Missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4:8 | c(4, 5, 7) | 4:8 |
| B | 7:12 | c(7, 8, 9, 10, 12) | 7:12 |
| C | 6:11 | c(6, 8, 11) | 6:11 |

Is there any way that I can compare the two lists (Observed vs. Expected) per group, so I can see which values are missing per group? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide reproducible data.

Comment: EmmaV97, your sample data is suggesting that the `Observed` column is a list-column, but list-columns in R generally don't display the wrapping `c(` and `)`. This suggests to me that those columns are _strings_, which changes how answers should prep the data (meaning: anything using _just_ `setdiff` is unlikely to work). The best mechanism for questions with ambiguous data like this is to paste the output from `dput(x)` into your question (in a code block) so that we can see with clarity the real underlying structure of the data.

Comment: As a quick demonstration, see and understand (immediately) the distinction between `structure(list(a = list(c("A", "B"), 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))` (list-column) and `structure(list(a = c("c(A, B)", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))` (normal column of strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have lists, use `Map` with `setdiff` -

```
df$Missing <- Map(setdiff, df$Expected, df$Observed)
df

#  Group            Expected        Observed Missing
#1     A       4, 5, 6, 7, 8         4, 5, 7    6, 8
#2     B 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 7, 8, 9, 10, 12      11
#3     C      6, 7, 8, 9, 10        6, 8, 10    7, 9
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "C"), Expected = list(4:8, 
    7:12, 6:10), Observed = list(c(4, 5, 7), c(7, 8, 9, 10, 12
), c(6, 8, 10))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe it was such a simple solution :) It works perfectly! Next time I'll make my data more reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

With a `data.table` anti-join:

```
library(data.table)

dt[
  dt[,.(x = unlist(Expected)), Group][
    !dt[,.(x = unlist(Observed)), Group], on = .(Group, x)
  ][, .(x = .(x)), Group], on = "Group", Missing := x
][]
#>    Group          Expected       Observed  Missing
#> 1:     A         4,5,6,7,8          4,5,7      6,8
#> 2:     B  7, 8, 9,10,11,12  7, 8, 9,10,12       11
#> 3:     C  6, 7, 8, 9,10,11        6, 8,10  7, 9,11
```

With `data.table` grouping operations:

```
library(collapse) # for %!in%

dt[,Missing := .(.(Expected[[1]][Expected %!in% Observed])), Group][]
#>    Group          Expected       Observed  Missing
#> 1:     A         4,5,6,7,8          4,5,7      6,8
#> 2:     B  7, 8, 9,10,11,12  7, 8, 9,10,12       11
#> 3:     C  6, 7, 8, 9,10,11        6, 8,10  7, 9,11
dt[
  ,.(
    Expected = Expected,
    Observed = Observed,
    Missing = .(setdiff(Expected[[1]], Observed[[1]]))
  ), Group
][]
#>    Group          Expected       Observed  Missing
#> 1:     A         4,5,6,7,8          4,5,7      6,8
#> 2:     B  7, 8, 9,10,11,12  7, 8, 9,10,12       11
#> 3:     C  6, 7, 8, 9,10,11        6, 8,10  7, 9,11
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  Group = LETTERS[1:3],
  Expected = list(4:8, 7:12, 6:11),
  Observed = list((4:7)[-3], (7:12)[-5], c(6L, 8L, 10L))
)
```

Benchmarking on a larger dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(
  Group = 1:1e4,
  Expected = lapply(sample(10, 1e4, 1), seq, 20)
)[, Observed := lapply(Expected, \(x) sample(x, sample(length(x), 1)))]

bench::mark(
  Map = {dt$Missing <- Map(setdiff, dt$Expected, dt$Observed); dt},
  setdiff = dt[,.(Expected = Expected, Observed = Observed, Missing = .(setdiff(Expected[[1]], Observed[[1]]))), Group],
  `%!in%` = dt[,Missing := .(.(Expected[[1]][Expected %!in% Observed])), Group],
  antiJoin = dt[
    dt[,.(x = unlist(Expected)), Group][
      !dt[,.(x = unlist(Observed)), Group], on = .(Group, x)
    ][, .(x = .(x)), Group], on = "Group", Missing := x
  ]
)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 Map          82.4ms   88.9ms      9.81     1.7MB     25.5
#> 2 setdiff     106.8ms  111.7ms      8.84    1.98MB     15.9
#> 3 %!in%        30.6ms   33.7ms     28.9   149.84KB     15.4
#> 4 antiJoin     53.8ms     58ms     16.8    12.04MB     14.9
```

Looks like `%!in%` is the winner so far.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @RonakShah, with `tidyverse` approach

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Missing = purrr::map2(Expected, Observed, setdiff))

  Group            Expected        Observed Missing
1     A       4, 5, 6, 7, 8         4, 5, 7    6, 8
2     B 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 7, 8, 9, 10, 12      11
3     C      6, 7, 8, 9, 10        6, 8, 10    7, 9
```

Comment: This works well, but is logically/effectively just a rewrite of @RonakShah's answer with `Map` using `purrr`'s nearly-equivalent `map2` function.

Comment: @r2evans It was intended to be a tidyverse option to consider, as solutions using data.table and base have already been posted. I'll add a comment to give credit.

Comment: It's not as much a criticism (this kind of multi-dialect multi-answer thing happens a lot), it's as much a comment for others learning to "translate" between base and tidyverse. The `purrr` function most like `Map` is `purrr::pmap`, which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. Often in my answers I'll provide all three variants to further help with "equivalency" and dialect-translation.